# Creating a collection of populations

Tags: anylogic

Currently working on a scalable model for a manufacturing company. The model is required to allow products to go through a series of processes, and I am trying to model each process as its population of agents so that the process can be scaled up in quantity easily. However, I need to set in a list (or work plan) for each product containing the population of agents that they are required to pass through. How can I create a collection to store these different sets of populations of agents?

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag the Collection element from the Agent palette onto the graphical diagram of agent type or experiment.
2. Name it. For example, `myCollection`
3. Choose the type you want: ARRAYLIST, LINKEDLIST, LINKEDHASHSET, TREESET, TREEMAP, LINKEDHASHMAP
4. Choose the element class. Maybe `Object` or `Agent`.
5. Use `myCollection.add(agent)` to add the agents you want to the collection.

Comment: I'm adding the population of the agent to the collection. Not the agent

Comment: You can add all the agents of all the populations that you think should be inside the same collection. In any case, as a 3-year intense AnyLogic developer, I don't see a big meaning in doing this. You probably can achieve this in more elegant ways..depending on what you eventually want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not trying to add all the agents to the collection. I want to store the population of the entire agents in the collection so for example, I have a population of process A. Then I want to store all this population in the collection so that when the product needs to go through process A, I can just find the first available agent within this population. But I have an entire list of processes (Process A - E) for example.

Comment: Why not to have a parameter for each agent called `process` and upon their generation add to the collection called `processA`, `processB`, etc. based on `agent.process==X`?

Comment: That only tracks the list of processes. I'm using enter and exits flows, so this means that ultimately ill still need to hard code if Process == Process A, pop_ProcessA.findFirst.... So what I'm hoping to do is directly add pop_ProcessA into a collection, so I can just use col_Processes.get(0).findFirst...

Comment: If all the agents of a population will have the same process, you don't need to do `agent.process==X`. Upon creation, you know the agent type and which process it will go through

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the context on my side, but let's not dive deeper on that. Just want to know if there are any methods to create a collection for populations of agents. If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you store each collection in a hashmap? Use the A,B,etc as the key?

HashMap<String, ArrayList> hmAgentLists = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

you can add different collections of agents to that, and then grab the right one using the key.